# What is Chiphacker?

Tags: discussion

New users probably knowing nothing about Chiphacker and the intent of this question is becoming a reference for them.

So, what is the history of the site Chiphacker?

Comment: hopefully one person can write up one good answer and it can be accepted, I am not sure this needs CW, we will see.

Comment: Something long dead and best forgotten?

Comment: @Nick, I don't know. We have a mod that [still type "chiphacker.com" to visit this site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-13830).

Comment: This doesn't need to be CW.  There's nothing wrong with getting rep on Meta! See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/how-relevant-is-rep-and-community-wiki-on-meta-stackoverflow) on MSO, and follow the links there for some more discussion on the role of community wiki questions on Meta sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chiphacker was a Q&A site running the old Stack Exchange platform which was created and administered by [Marcus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3/littlebirdceo) and [Maddy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/21/mad-z) of [littlebirdelectronics.com](http://littlebirdelectronics.com/) as an auxiliary support line for their Sparkfun-like, Sydney-based online electronics shop.  It featured the much-loved Electropus (excellent image below found on the [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/chiphackers) account).

[image: Electropus]

While Chiphacker had a fairly vibrant and healthy community (unlike its sister site/competitor [Electronics Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1256/857)), it wasn't as successful as it could be, and other SE 1.0 sites were struggling. Stack Exchange Inc. opted to phase out SE 1.0 sites, and [started Area51](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/).

[image: Area51 banner]

The Electronics and Robotics proposal on Area51 was created to replace Chiphacker:

> This would be the SE 2.0 version of Chiphacker – Jared Harley Jun 3 [of 2010] at 2:55

At one time, there were [three Electronics Stackexchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55453/multiple-electronics-se-sites)!  [This question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/857) and [this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597/857) are informative with respect to the migration.  In the end, Chiphacker's content (both users and questions/answers) were migrated to the new site, while Electronics Exchange content was dropped.

The original name of the Area51 site was "Electronics and Robotics."  After some discussion about creating a [robotics-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/robooverflow) [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59408/146495), discussion about allowing robotics on the site (for example, [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/857) and [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/lego-mindstorms-robotics-on-topic)), it was decided to [remove Robotics from the title and scope](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/electronics-and-robotics-has-been-renamed-to-electronics).

This resulted in the name "Electronics", which was used during the beta period.  However, this [caused great stress](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/857) about the potential for a flood of consumer electronics questions, and we launched as "Electronics Design".

Unfortunately, this caused us to [run afoul of someone's trademark](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/565/857).  Therefore, we were renamed to "Electronics Engineering", which is our current name.  Of course, there are [other names that have been proposed](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/will-this-site-retain-the-chiphacker-name)...The history isn't over yet!

Answer (score 2):

Chiphacker was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

The content of that Stack Exchange 1.0 site, with permission from the site owner, was merged with this Stack Exchange 2.0 site.